# GCP Load balancer terraform recipe for api gateway returns 404

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have created an LB for the api gateway using [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/gateway-serverless-neg) and it works fine, but after creating it using the terraform recipe it gives me a `404 page not found`. These are the terraform resources for my load balancer. I have added the api gateway with terraform and it works for the LB added on gcloud console, and also tested the cloud function I have behind the api gateway and that works fine too. so I'm pretty sure the problem is with the LB. Any ideas anyone?

```
resource "google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group" "function_neg_us" {
  name                  =  var.neg_us_id.name 
  provider              = google-beta
  network_endpoint_type = "SERVERLESS"
  region                =  var.neg_us_id.region #"us-east1"
  serverless_deployment{
    platform = "apigateway.googleapis.com"
    resource = var.neg_us_id.gateway
  }
}

resource "google_compute_backend_service" "webservers_backend_service_us" {
  name                            =  var.neg_us_id.backend_srv
  timeout_sec                     = 30
  provider              = google-beta
  connection_draining_timeout_sec = 0
  load_balancing_scheme = "EXTERNAL"
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  log_config {
    enable = true
    sample_rate  = 1
  }

  backend {
    group = google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group.function_neg_us.id
    balancing_mode = "UTILIZATION"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_url_map" "lb_us" {

  name            = "url-map-us"
  provider        = google-beta
  default_service = google_compute_backend_service.webservers_backend_service_us.id
  host_rule {
    hosts        = [var.domain_name_us]
    path_matcher = "us-predictions"
  }
    path_matcher {
    name            = "us-predictions"
    default_service = google_compute_backend_service.webservers_backend_service_us.id
  }
}

resource "google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate" "lb_ssl_cert_us" {
  name     = "us-predictions-test-terraform"

  managed {
    domains = [var.domain_name_us]
  }
}

resource "google_compute_target_https_proxy" "lb_us_proxy" {
  name     = "us-https-proxy-test-terraform"
  url_map  = google_compute_url_map.lb_us.id
  provider              = google-beta
  ssl_certificates = [
    google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.lb_ssl_cert_us.id
  ]
  depends_on = [
    google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.lb_ssl_cert_us
  ]
}
# reserved IP address 8
resource "google_compute_global_address" "ip_address_us" {
  name = "ssl-proxy-xlb-ip-terraform-us"
}

resource "google_compute_global_forwarding_rule" "rule_us" {
  name                  = "ssl-proxy-xlb-forwarding-rule-us"
  provider              = google-beta
  ip_protocol           = "TCP"
  load_balancing_scheme = "EXTERNAL"
  port_range            = 443
  target                = google_compute_target_https_proxy.lb_us_proxy.id
  ip_address            = google_compute_global_address.ip_address_us.id
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recipe was correct. I have added the wrong value for the resource of  google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group. Fixed that and it's working now.